# conversion of time in the entire column to string

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, data-science

I want to change the time in the entire column to strings. Please provide the method with an example.
Given below is my data.

```
timeseries  CCN Number Conc SS
0   00:00:00    15.810967   0.1
1   00:05:00    358.401000  0.3
2   00:10:00    797.538333  0.5
```

given below is my code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
load_file=pd.read_excel(r'E:\CCNC\CCNCCodes\Modulated output\Copy of Final_modulated_ccnc_data.xlsx',header=0)
load_file.columns
s=load_file.loc[0:289,['Timeseries',' CCN Number Conc','SS']]
```

Thank you.

Comment: ```df['your_clm'] = df['your_clm'].astype(str)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tell Pandas to load the columns you want as strings:

```
pd.read_excel(filename, dtype={'Timeseries': str}, header=0)
```

That way you don't have to convert them later, which would waste time.

Comment: Dear John, solution provided by you is more feasible . Thanks buddy.